# How can I return the sum and average of an int array?

Tags: c#

I need to define two methods for returning the `sum` and `average` of an int array. The method defining is as follow:-

```
public int Sum(params int[] customerssalary)
{
           
         // I tried the following but it fails   return customerssalary.sum();
}
```

Another question is, how can I return the average of these int values?

Comment: You sure `return ints.sum();` doesn't work? Why on earth would that not work?!?!?

Comment: sorry i meant customerssalary.sum(); did nto work

Comment: Dear, I guess you are using .net 2.0 .. So please check this first

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is the way you should be doing it, and I say this because you are clearly new to C# and should probably try to understand how some basic stuff works!

```
public int Sum(params int[] customerssalary)
{
   int result = 0;

   for(int i = 0; i < customerssalary.Length; i++)
   {
      result += customerssalary[i];
   }

   return result;
}
```

with this `Sum` function, you can use this to calculate the average too...

```
public decimal Average(params int[] customerssalary)
{
   int sum = Sum(customerssalary);
   decimal result = (decimal)sum / customerssalary.Length;
   return result;
}
```

the reason for using a `decimal` type in the second function is because the division can easily return a non-integer result

---

Others have provided a Linq alternative which is what I would use myself anyway, but with Linq there is no point in having your own functions anyway. I have made the assumption that you have been asked to implement such functions as a task to demonstrate your understanding of C#, but I could be wrong.

Comment: `decimal result = sum / customerssalary.Length` will calculate the division as an integer and then store it in a decimal. You need to cast one of the two arguments as a decimal/float/whatever before performing the division.

Comment: @Rawling: Eh?... dunno what you mean :P

Comment: if you have `int`s `a` and `b`, `a/b` performs integer divisions (e.g. `7/2` gives `3`). It doesn't matter if you store it in an `int` or a `decimal`, it still performs integer division.

Comment: @Rawling... yeah my comment was a joke, perhaps you can see I had already changed it after your suggestion

Comment: Sarcasm detection obviously offline this morning :-/ sorry!

Answer (score 52):

```
customerssalary.Average();
customerssalary.Sum();
```

Comment: The best and easiest way. Requires Linq

Answer (score 15):

Using `ints.sum()` has two problems:

- The variable is called `customerssalary`, not `ints`
- C# is case sensitive - the method is called `Sum()`, not `sum()`.

Additionally, you'll need a using directive of

```
using System.Linq;
```

Once you've got the sum, you can just divide by the length of the array to get the average - you don't need to use `Average()` which will iterate over the array again.

```
int sum = customerssalary.Sum();
int average = sum / customerssalary.Length;
```

or as a `double`:

```
double average = ((double) sum) / customerssalary.Length;
```

Comment: (Sorry if this is the wrong place to ask this) When using the Average method, it returns a decimal but the recommendation here and on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb354760.aspx) appears to be for double can I ask why?

Comment: Ah, worked it out, it depends on the input, I will leave this comment here for anyone else pondering the same.

Comment: +1 for mentioning `using System.Linq;` because if it is missing, Visual Studio does not add automatically.

Answer (score 3):

Though the answers above all are different flavors of correct, I'd like to offer the following solution, which includes a null check:

```
decimal sum = (customerssalary == null) ? 0 : customerssalary.Sum();
decimal avg = (customerssalary == null) ? 0 : customerssalary.Average();
```

Answer (score 2):

You have tried the wrong variable, `ints` is not the correct name of the argument.

```
public int Sum(params int[] customerssalary)
{
    return customerssalary.Sum();
}

public double Avg(params int[] customerssalary)
{
    return customerssalary.Average();
}
```

But do you think that these methods are really needed?

Comment: I think they will be needed if he wants to pass his homework assignment ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using visual studio 2005 then

```
public void sumAverageElements(int[] arr)
{
     int size =arr.Length;
     int sum = 0;
     int average = 0;

     for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
     {
          sum += arr[i];
     }

     average = sum / size; // sum divided by total elements in array

     Console.WriteLine("The Sum Of Array Elements Is : " + sum);
     Console.WriteLine("The Average Of Array Elements Is : " + average);
}
```

Comment: yeah... this doesn't really help to *return* the values from *two* functions does it. Also, what about when the average is a non-integer value?

Comment: This method can be split into two right..I was just providing the logic.

Answer (score 0):

i refer so many results and modified my code its working

```
foreach (var rate in rateing)
                {
                    sum += Convert.ToInt32(rate.Rate);
                }
                if(rateing.Count()!= 0)
                {
                    float avg = (float)sum / (float)rateing.Count();
                    saloonusers.Rate = avg;
                }
                else
                {
                    saloonusers.Rate = (float)0.0;
                }
```