# Array Average Method Error

Tags: c#

I am getting an error

> Error CS1929  'uint[]' does not contain a definition for 'Average' and
>   the best extension method overload
>   'Queryable.Average(IQueryable)' requires a receiver of type
>   'IQueryable' ArrayLengthTest D:\Visual
>   Studio\ArrayLengthTest\ArrayLengthTest\Program.cs 17  Active

```
uint[] asd = new uint[5];
            for (uint i = 0; i < asd.Length; i++)
            {
                asd[i] = i;
            }
            uint arrayAverage = asd.Average();
```

Any ideas what does it mean? I know that I can easily use ints but I am asking for uints...

Comment: It means there's no such method as Average() on uint[].

Comment: You can have a [look at the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358602(v=vs.110).aspx). `uint[]` doesn't have the `Average()` function.

Comment: @DrewKennedy and why it doesn't have? I mean if you need it... ofc the result will be approximately since Average returns double type... but still?

Comment: @rene not a duplicate.. I know that i can use int to calculate the average, but my question is if i want to use uint for average...

Comment: Here's a question about why `int` is preferred over `uint` in the framework, I think that's as close to an answer as you can get.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/782629/why-does-net-use-int-instead-of-uint-in-certain-classes

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
using System.Linq;
```

or see this post [how-can-i-return-the-sum-average-of-an-int-array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12949978/3365997)

UPDATE
[using refl] you can try to implement your custom Avarage extension
[this is a semple idea]

```
public static uint Average(this IEnumerable<uint> source)
    {
        if (source == null) throw new Exception(); 
        long sum = 0;
        long count = 0;
        checked
        {
            foreach (uint v in source)
            {
                sum += v;
                count++;
            }
        }
        if (count > 0) return(uint)((double)sum / count);
        throw new Exception();
    }
```

Comment: The question seems to be about why there isn't a version of `Average` in Linq that handles `uint` specifically.

Comment: Sorry for my wrong suggestion.